# Open subl url in Ubuntu with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, rails, sublime-text

I have a project in Rails and I'm using [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) which generate error pages with links to files where is originated a specific error. These links are something like:

```
subl://open?url=file://path/to/my/file&line=line_number_where_the_error_happens
```

Now when I click the link in chrome is asking me to use `xdg-open` to open it, but is just opening another empty chrome window. Should I configure chrome to open these kind of links with sublime text? Or I must to configure xdg-open to open with sublime this specific kind? And how can I do it?

Comment: Why this question is a duplicate if it was made before than the other?